# Error (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:)

Tags: python

Intento ejecutar este script y por mucho que he revisado no encuentro el error que me da al final.

El directorio es correcto, sino no leería parte del script.

El script contiene una función (`follower_scatter_plot`) que dibuja gráficos, y el código que da error es este:

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as bk
handle = "barripdmx"
df = pd.read_csv ( handle + "_followers.csv")
p = follower_scatter_plot (df, handle, color=(140,0,70))
bk.show (p)
```

El proceso que indica el error (resumido) es este:
File "C:\Users\barri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 702, in get_handle
handle = open(
*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'barripdmx_followers.csv'*

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola JAvier, bienvenido. Parece que el archivo que intentas abrir no existe. No me deja acceder a tu código, así que poco más puedo ayudarte.

Comment: Tienes el archivo de Drive en privado y lo ejecutas en IDE o Terminal?

Comment: abre tu explorador de archivos, dirígete a la ubicación del archivo, copia la ruta y pégala. Problema resuelto :)

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema viene dado porque el archivo donde están los datos que deben dibujarse (`barripdmx_followers.csv`) no se encuentra en el directorio desde el que se ejecuta el script.

Te lo deja bastante claro en esta línea del error:

`**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'barripdmx_followers.csv'**`

Tienes dos opciones: O mueves el archivo al mismo directorio donde ejecutas el script, o modificas este para indicarle donde se encuentra el archivo, con la ruta completa. Lo puedes hacer cambiando la variable `'handle'` y recuerda que debes poner dos barras invertidas para indicar los cambios de directorio. Por ejemplo: `C:\\directorio\\directorio\\barripdmx` ; sin embargo, hay que tener en cuenta que la variable `handle` también se usa para el título del gráfico que se dibuja, por lo que no parece la mejor opción.

Comment: Tu respuesta se vuelve inútil al no saber el código original. Cuando el enlace deje de ser válido tu respuesta no tendrá sentido y solo ayuda al AP. Puedes editar la pregunta agregando todo lo del enlace, lo cual vendría muy bien para la pregunta y tu respuesta

Comment: Pues tienes razón. Estoy aprendiendo a usar el site y aún tengo mucho camino por hacer. Gracias por tu .. ¿aportación?

Comment: Cuando hagas una edición procura que se siga manteniendo la intención original del autor. He aprobado tu edición pero falta la revisión de otros usuario y  algunos notan que la intención se ha perdido. Y sí, mi comentario es un aporte, tal vez la intención no haya quedado clara pero era incentivarte a editar la pregunta para que fuese mejor :D

Comment: Siempre aprendiendo. Soy un alumno motivado. Gracias por vuestro apoyo.